# Capistrano 3 upgrade problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I've been trying to upgrade from Capistrano 2 to Capistrano 3, but have been working through all the errors. I'm stuck on one that I don't know how to solve now. I'm using Unicorn and Nginx.

Error trace:

```
cap production deploy:cold --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Task Argument Error
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:96:in `resolve_args_with_dependencies'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `resolve_args'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:24:in `define_task'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:360:in `define_task'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:32:in `task'
config/deploy.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:29:in `each'
config/deploy.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:196:in `in_namespace'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:104:in `namespace'
config/deploy.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `load'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/devanb/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
```

Deploy file:

```
set :application, 'liveinbham'
set :user, 'deployer'

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :scm, "git"
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:DevanB/LIveInBham.git'
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm_verbose, true
set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :git_enable_submodules, 1

set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, "production"
set :branch, "master"

set :pty, true

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}

set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do
  %w{start stop restart}.each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:application)}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)}"
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end

desc "tail log files"
task :tail, :roles => :app do
  run "tail -f /home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}/current/log/production.log" do |channel, stream, data|
    puts "#{channel[:host]}: #{data}"
    break if stream == :err
  end
end

desc "Open the rails console on one of the remote servers"
task :console, :roles => :app do
  hostname = find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
  exec "ssh -l #{fetch(:user)} #{hostname} -t 'source ~/.profile && #{current_path}/script/rails c #{fetch(:rails_env)}'"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be a few things but `deploy:cold` is depreciated in Capistrano 3, I've just tried it and I just get "don't know how to build task" which is what I'd expect. Potentially running `deploy:setup_config` and then just a straight up `deploy` may work.

There's a few other things which will need tweaking like you can no longer use that approach for streaming log files, it's just a simple `execute` instead. E.g.:

```
namespace :logs do
  desc "tail rails logs" 
  task :tail_rails do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "tail -f #{shared_path}/log/#{fetch(:rails_env)}.log"
    end
  end
end
```

In general the task definition format also needs updating, e.g:

```
task :setup_config, roles: :app do
  # some stuff
end
```

would become

```
task :setup_config do
  on roles(:app) do
     #some stuff
  end
end
```

It looks like your Cap 2 configuration is based quite heavily on the Railscast about it. Mine also was and I recently went through the process of migrating all the apps using it to a new Cap 3 one. I've documented the approach I ended up with [here](http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/01/deploying-rails-apps-to-a-vps-with-capistrano-v3/) including the code.

Comment: Thanks again! 

Ran into a hiccup or two. First is dealing with Sidekiq.

    `cap aborted!`
    `cannot load such file -- sidekiq/capistrano`
    `/Users/dbeitel/Documents/Projects/LIveInBham/Capfile:19:in ``<top (required)>'`

Second is with rbenv.

    `cap aborted!`
    `Unable to activate capistrano-rbenv-2.0.0, because sshkit-1.3.0 conflicts with sshkit (~> 1.2.0)`
    `/Users/dbeitel/Documents/Projects/LIveInBham/Capfile:20:in ``<top (required)>'`

Comment: So your second error is because you've got a gem version conflict, you need to make sure you've only got one version of sshkit required. The first one looks like you're trying to require the sidekiq scripts without sidekiq installed. Few possible reasons. Are you using bundle exec? have you got a version of sidekiq installed which includes the capistrano 3 tasks?

Comment: Hope this helps http://tommytcchan.com/blog/2014/01/06/capistrano-3-and-rbenv-sshkit-upgrade-to-1-dot-3/

Comment: @TalkingQuickly I'm trying to follow your tutorial. I'm confused about where to find the deploy:setup_config task that you mention in your tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace makes it pretty clear.  The error comes from line 31 of your file, where you try to define a task using the old Capistrano 2 syntax.  The new Capistrano 3 uses Rake, so you must use Rake syntax to define tasks, with the aid of some Capistrano methods.  Rake does not recognize "roles" and "except".  TalkingQuickly gave a good-looking example of the new way to define tasks.